# Waiting Thread or Create New Thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

I have a decision to make regarding the way I code something, which is running on an embedded platform and am hoping there is a general "rule-of-thumb" that can be used in this case.  Coding both my ideas and then benchmarking would obviously be the best way to go, but to get any meaningful, or rather accurate results out of this platform, in my particular case, would be quite tricky.  I'm also sure that there may be others that are having the same question on their respective platforms, so I decided to ask it here.  Please be kind, as I'm not very familiar with the threading library, so constructive feedback would be useful.

I have many threads (well, about 10-20 at maximum) all wanting to write to this hardware device. So I decided on using a simple ring-buffer consisting of 2 buffers (primary/secondary) of 8k each. This way each in-coming thread could be dealt with in a timely fashion. An arriving thread would obtain a mutex and write into the primary buffer and then release its mutex ready for the next thread. Now when the primary buffer is full, new incoming threads obviously switch to using the secondary buffer and then you start to write the primary buffer to the hardware device.

So the question really is... How best to write to the hardware device??? I'm thinking that there are two choices:

1. As soon as the buffer is full, create a new thread that does the write operation.
2. Signal a pre-created waiting worker-thread to do the write operation.

Both of the options seem to come with their respective pros/cons.  Option 1 is the simplest to code and there are a number of ways to do this, but its effectiveness is dependent on how expensive it is to create/start the thread.  The thread would be created, it would perform the write operation and then it would die.  Option 2 however seems to be the most performant, but if you're going to have a reusable thread, you're going to need a mutex and a couple condition variables to control it.  One to notify the thread that data is ready and another to ask for the thread to terminate when the program ends. Add to that a sprinkle of atomics for spurious wake-ups/missing notifications etc, and you've got quite an intricate solution to get right.

So what *is* the best method here?  Are threads in general heavy to create/start or is this something that is completely platform dependent and benchmarking is the only way to know? Is there any benefit to using one method over the other that I've not thought about?

**-- This is for the people not suffering from TL;DR syndrome --**

I'm sure some of you have already wondered what happens if the secondary buffer becomes full before the write operation has finished?  The answer in my case is fairly simple: this should never happen! Although the write operation is slow, it would never be slow enough such that the secondary buffer is filled before the write is complete.  However, if someone is going to use this ring-buffer method, they must be prepared for this contingency.  The way I thought about tackling this is to have a second mutex that is held during the write operation. This would mean that the thread that was due to write to the buffer would block until the write completed and the mutex was released.

Here's what I roughly ended up with after going with Option 2, but it seems awfully messy.  I actually wanted to use promise/futures to avoid the spin-lock predicates on the condition variable, but couldn't think of a good way of moving a promise to an already created thread.  Anyway...  nice feedback is appreciated, bad-feedback, well, I'm not overly familiar with the threading library.

```
class Bar
{
    public:
        Bar(const size_t size) : buffer(new uint8_t[size]), buffer_size(size), used_size(0) {}
        const size_t GetRemainingBufferSize(void) const { return buffer_size - used_size; }
        const size_t GetUsedBufferSize(void) const { return used_size; }
        const uint8_t* GetBuffer(void) const { return buffer.get(); }
        const size_t GetBufferSize() const { return buffer_size; }
        void ResetBuffer(void) { used_size = 0; }
        void WriteIntoBuffer(const vector<uint8_t>& data)
        {
            std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), buffer.get() + used_size);
            used_size += data.size();
        }
        private:
            std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> buffer;
        size_t buffer_size;
        size_t used_size;
};

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(const size_t buffer_size = 8192) : bar_buffers{ buffer_size, buffer_size }, primary_buffer(&bar_buffers[0]), secondary_buffer(&bar_buffers[1]),
            write_predicate(false), quit_predicate(false), write_buffer(primary_buffer)
        {
            foo_thread = std::thread(&Foo::WriteHWThread, this);
        }
        ~Foo()
        {
        quit_predicate = true;
        begin_write.notify_one();
        if (foo_thread.joinable())
            foo_thread.join();
        }
        Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
        Foo& operator=(const Foo&) = delete;
        void WriteData(const std::vector<uint8_t>& data)
        {
            if (std::lock_guard<std::mutex> foo_lk(foo_lock); primary_buffer->GetRemainingBufferSize() < data.size())
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> write_lk(write_lock);
                write_buffer = primary_buffer;
                write_lk.unlock();
                std::swap(primary_buffer, secondary_buffer);
                primary_buffer->ResetBuffer();
                write_predicate = true;
                begin_write.notify_one();
            }
            primary_buffer->WriteIntoBuffer(data);
        }
        void WriteHWThread(void)
        {
            do
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> write_lk(write_lock);
                begin_write.wait(write_lk, [&]() -> bool { return write_predicate.load() || quit_predicate.load(); });
                write_predicate = false;
                if (write_buffer.load()->GetUsedBufferSize())
                    <<< WRITE TO DEDICATED HARDWARE >>>
                write_lk.unlock();
            } while (!quit_predicate);
        }
    private:
        Bar bar_buffers[2];
        Bar* primary_buffer, *secondary_buffer;
        std::atomic<bool> write_predicate, quit_predicate;
        std::atomic<Bar*> write_buffer;
        std::mutex foo_lock, write_lock;
        std::thread foo_thread;
        std::condition_variable begin_write;
};
```

Comment: look into lock free buffer

Comment: Does this "embedded platform" have 10-20 feral hogs, I mean CPUs, to run all those those threads? Why do you need so many threads on the first place? Maybe that device supports asynchronous io?

Comment: As this is mainly a question about design decisions I suggest creating a class purely for dealing with one buffer in a thread safe manner and with no writing to H/W or anything. Just make it safe to put stuff in the buffer and to extract it from it. It'll be easier to understand what's what when reading the code later. Creating threads is not free of charge so I also suggest having the writing thread alive - or just let the thread that filled the buffer write it to H/W.